# Wann benutzt man "wenn" oder "ob"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, usage

Ich glaube, dass *ob* wie das englische *if* ist und *wenn* wie das englische *whether*.

Also *ob* mit Kondition, *whether* in allen anderen Fällen. Ist das richtig?

**Beispiele**

Ich weiß nicht, ob ich Zeit habe.
Ruf mich an, ob du Zeit hast

Ich rufe dich an, wenn ich Zeit habe.

Comment: There is a good summary here: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/tag/difference-wenn-ob/ I find the general rule "use ob for yes/no questions" usually helps, but the blog I posted has some examples where that rule would have made me make a mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately people downvoted this question without further explanation. We can only guess why that was so. It may help you [edit] the question to give us some examples where you struggle with using "ob" *vs.* "wenn" in translation of "if" or "whether".

Comment: @DavidHall This is good, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Elena - I'd feel like a heel posting someone's blog post as my own answer :) If joe feels like it really helps him and no better answer is given, he can post it. I just come here to improve my German and share things I've learned :)

Comment: DavidHall: we dont like a simple copy & paste of copyright protected content without proper attribution. In this case  we should ask @Emanuel who made the blog, and is also a user here, to shed some light on that matter ;)

Comment: @Takkat exactly :) I actually found the blog from one of Emanuel's posts here. I was also puzzled by the downvote - for me this is a great questions. I've studied German to the level where I can (apparently) study at an advanced level (C2) and was *always* corrected for using wenn instead of ob by me teacher.

Answer (score 3):

The blog David Hall mentioned in his comment to the question ([this one](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/tag/difference-wenn-ob/)) covers the `ob` part very well, but your question differs slightly. So, we should shift the focus a little bit:

If you want to express a conditional like

> If it is good wheather tomorrow, I will play football.

you *cannot* use `ob` but have to use `wenn` or `falls`:

> Wenn morgen schönes Wetter ist, werde ich Fußball spielen.

If you want to express an uncertainty/several possibilities like

> I don't know, whether I have time.

you *should not* use `wenn/falls` but should use `ob`:

> Ich weiß nicht, ob ich Zeit habe.

Remark: You can use `wenn/falls` in the second case, but you will mean something different, and in this case strange, thing:

> Ich weiß nicht, wenn ich Zeit habe. = In case I have time, then I don't know (what to do).

This sentence is grammatically correct and might be suitable depending on context, but out of context it is missing the information, what `I don't know`.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich glaube, dass *ob* wie das englische *if* ist und *wenn* wie das englische *whether*.

To me it seems rather the other way round.

- **ob** - **whether**
- **wenn** / falls - **if**

> Ich weiß nicht, ob ich Zeit habe.
>   I'm not sure, whether I have the time.
>
> Ich rufe dich an, wenn ich Zeit habe.
>   I call you, if I have the time.